# How to copy one storage account's container's blobs to another storage account's container's blobs

Tags: azure, ms-access, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I have two storage accounts(`storage1`) and (`storage2`) and both of them have containers called `data`.

Now, `storage1`'s `data` contains folder called `database-files` which contains lots of folders recursively. I mean it's kind of huge.

What I am trying to do is I want to copy `database-files` and everything that's in it from `storage1`'s `data` container to `storage2`'s data container. **Note:** both storage accounts are in the same resource group and subscription.

Here is what I've tried:

`az storage blob copy start-batch --source-account-name "storage1" --source-container "data" --account-name "storage2" --destination-container "data"`

This worked fine, but The problem is time it takes is ridiculously big and I can't wait this much because I want to do this command for one of my release . Which means that i need this as soon as fast, so that my deployment happens fast.

Is there any way to make it faster? maybe `zip it/copy it/unzip` it? Even If I use `AzCopy`, I have no idea how it's going to help with timing. All it helps is it doesn't have point of failure and also I have no idea how to use it via `azure cli`.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Do you think about using Data Factory?

Comment: I tried azcopy from my local machine and it worked much faster. I want to use azcopy. but now, i got a problem that how do i use it in azure-cli, because for my release pipeline, i have inline script in which i use commands such as call az storage. no idea how to use azcopy in there. what do you think?

Comment: Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops. HTH.

Comment: I want it to be part of release, not build

Comment: it's also for the release. great. does it use azcopy by default ?

Comment: Reference this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/copy-blobs-from-command-line-and-code/ may be helpful.

Comment: @NikaKurashvili Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/storage-preview/storage/azcopy?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-storage-preview-az-storage-azcopy-run-command

Comment: Hi @NikaKurashvil, did you get the best solution now?